# Virtual DOM creation order. Which node created first?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know how virtual DOM is being built in React. Root element first or last.

For example I have such code:

```js
const A = () => <h1>Wonderful Application</h1>

const App = () => (
 <div>
  <A/>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
);


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

We all know that after transpiling this code will look like this:

```js
const A = () => React.createElement("h1", null, "Wonderful Application");

const App = () => React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(A, null), React.createElement("ul", {
  id: "nav"
}, React.createElement("li", null, React.createElement("a", {
  href: "#"
}, "Home")), React.createElement("li", null, React.createElement("a", {
  href: "#"
}, "About")), React.createElement("li", null, React.createElement("a", {
  href: "#"
}, "Clients")), React.createElement("li", null, React.createElement("a", {
  href: "#"
}, "Contact Us"))));

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

So which react element is created first - root element or inner element. 
Which function is called first - inner or outer? How does this large Virtual Dom object grow?

Comment: I would *expect* it goes inner to outer, since you have to attach a child to something and doing it in a depth-first manner is the easiest. But I've no actual proof of this. Does it really matter or is it more of an academic curiosity?

Comment: That for educational purposes. Just to know better how React works

Comment: @sgko as per my deleted answer, I presume they are created as they are processed (so `parent` -> `child`). However, as I mentioned in another comment, this is very much an implementation detail that could easily change. It's not even clear from [the docs](https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture/blob/master/README.md) which I think is probably intentional.

Comment: I thought that functions are probably invoked starting from outer function. But can it be so that the inner function returns smth first, then outer function appends something else to the result of first return? I am not sure but it looks like we call outer function first, but inner function pass result to outer function, and latter process it?

Comment: If the example you've given is _exactly_ how React is transpiled, then the children would be created first because that's generally how a call stack works (LIFO).

Comment: The example was transpiled with babeljs.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.createElement` creates virtual dom, and `document.createElement` creates real dom. So if we know each the call order of `React.createDOM/document.createElement`, we can know the order of element creation as well.

As show bellow, I rewrite those functions in order to know when they are called:

```html
<!-- load essencial libs -->
<div id="app"></div>
<script>
React.createElement = (fn => (...params) => {
  console.log('call React.createElement and params is')
  console.log(params[0])
  return fn.apply(React, params)
})(React.createElement)
document.createElement = (fn => (...params) => {
  console.log('call document.createElement, and param is')
  console.log(params[0])
  return fn.apply(document, params)
})(document.createElement)

const App = React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  React.createElement(
    'span',
    null,
    'text'
  )
)
ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('app'))
</script>
```

and the output is:

```
call React.createElement, and param is
span
call React.createElement, and param is
div
call createElement, and param is
span
call createElement, and param is
div
```

So children element are created first, both of virtual dom and real dom.